# Move data from google drive to a repository which is cloned from github

Tags: python, database, github, google-colaboratory, git-clone

I have cloned a repository from github to a colab notebook. Now I want to add some data from my google drive to one of the folders cloned from github. How should I proceed? Thanks for any guidance or suggestions!

Comment: Actually, my main problem is that cloning a repository on colab is different from what we get in a personal computer. The platform disconnects and all folders disappear.

Answer (score 0):

To work with any google services, especially the ones which need special authentication like drive, you need to create a Google service via google API package by providing the right auth credentials like API-key or JSON key.

here is the official API package of google APIs in python [google-api-python-client](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/)

if you want an abstraction from making a service you can use [PyDrive](https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/)

Basically, you gonna download the data by connecting to the drive into your colab folder